# ESLint : Timeout on starting language service process in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, eslint, webstorm, tslint

I'm having this error in WebStorm with React and TypeScript:

[image]

This is how my node environment is setup in WebStorm:

[image]

This is my ESLint configuration in WebStorm and TSLint is not working properly, it doesn't detect errors:

[image]

Comment: Please report this issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install / reinstall global eslint, in my case it helped

```
npm install --g eslint
```

Make sure that you choose "Automatic ES Lint Configuration"

Restart your software and check the results